# SQL in VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Function, and I want to add the following SQL, however being a newbie I don't know how to break the query in the code.

The query:

```
 strSQL = "select (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID) AS NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS_NOT_DELETED FROM       CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT INNER JOIN
ACCOUNT ON CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID=ACCOUNT.ID
 WHERE
Convert(datetime,convert(char(10),[CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT].CREATED_ON,101))
BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-12-31' AND  CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.DELETED!='1' AND      ACCOUNT.DELETED !='1'
)
-
(SELECT    COUNT (DISTINCT dLOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS NOT_ACTIVE_ACCOUNTS

FROM         dbo.LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  ACCOUNT ON dbo.LOAD_ACCOUNT_DETAIL_0.ID = dbo.ACCOUNT.ID WHERE
ACCOUNT_STATUS !='1') AS DIFFERENCE
```

buting the whole thing in quotes dont work...!

Comment: 1. what, exactly, do you mean by it doesn't work?
2. I'm not sure your SQL is right in the first place.  That statement doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are running your query, you often have to break your query up into smaller chunks (less than ~200 characters, I forget exact amount).

This is done by breaking it into an array of strings:

Either:

```
QueryArry = Array("Your ","Query ","here ")
```

Using Marg's method this becomes:

```
QueryArry = Array("Your ", _
    "Query ", _
    "here ")
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
Dim QueryArry(0 to 100) as String
QueryArry(0)="Your "
QueryArry(1)="Query "
QueryArry(2)="Here "
```

**WARNING**: In every case make sure to add a space before the end of each quote... because these lines get appended together and without the extra space would be "YourQueryHere" Instead of "Your Query Here".

Dan

Comment: okkk.....but how do i execute the array?.. with one query i used this  
    Set rsData = objConn.Execute(strSQL)..now with the array? using this method:
Dim QueryArry(0 to 100) as String 
QueryArry(0)="Your " 
QueryArry(1)="Query " 
QueryArry(2)="Here "

Comment: Yes.  Set rsData = objConn.Execute(QueryArry)... though it depends on the rest of your code, but that should work.  If your getting strange error messages from the SQL, try running the SQL in another application... Excel doesn't give informative error messages, other programs will tell you where in the code there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim myString As String

myString = "You can " & _
    "use '& _' to concatenate " & _
    "strings over multiple lines."
```

Comment: +1 there is an upper limit on the number of concatenations - somewhere between 20 and 30 - in a single statement so you might have to build up a very long statement in stages

Answer (score 1):

You can also break it up like this:

```
strSQL = "select ( "
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID) AS NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS_NOT_DELETED FROM       CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT INNER JOIN "
strSQL = strSQL & "ACCOUNT ON CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID=ACCOUNT.ID "
...
```

I prefer this way to the strSQL = "..." & _ "..." & _ "..." over multiple lines, but potato / potato...